# get data from elasticsearch, mysql, google analytics, logs, and create statistic

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch, etl

I seek a freeware solution to grab data every day from miscellaneous data source and generate statistic like connection, visit, customer, sales, churn...
Can i need an ETL like Talend ? Or only scripting ? Some idea ? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Using a tool such as Talend is a better approach as it gives you, out of the box, a number of specialized components to achieve tasks that can be painful to realize by yourself. Once the learning curve has passed, it give your the opportunity to be very productive with the garanty to be able to deliver highly robust and performant jobs for a very large scope of use cases.
In most cases, Talend Data Integration commmunity is a very good place to start. You'll find a lot of documentation, videos and example to help you learn the basics and advanced topics. If necessary, you'll move to souscription edition later with the ability to keep all your jobs with you.

Hope this helps,

TRF